# Cordova plugin for push notification that listen to my own webservice

Tags: javascript, web-services, cordova, push-notification

I am building a [cordova](http://cordova.apache.org) mobile application which waits a message from my admin web application server.

The admin application is conected by tcp to a websocket server I implemented on top of [ratchet](http://socketo.me/) web socket server.

I implemented the binding to my ratchet web service and receiving the message in javascript by using websoket.

Now I want to notify the mobile if the server sends a message and the application is closed.
I want to display this message in the notifications list of the mobile.

After I googled this I found [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) and [Pushwoosh](https://github.com/Pushwoosh/phonegap-cordova-push-notifications) and others. 
 but they deppened on google and iphone services **GCM** and **ANPS** or a special web service that does not run on my server .

Is there a plugin that do so or is there a way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. You can use your own web service but you must cross over APNS and GCM before notification send to user device.

APNS for IOS

[image]

GCM for android

[image]