# Posting data from webservice to ionic app

Tags: android, ios, web-services, ionic-framework, windows-phone-8

Everyone, I am asking this because I really can't understand how I can send data from my `webservice(vb.net)` to my ionic app(android/ios/windows).

I used Firebase Cloud Messaging and it worked perfectly fine, but there's a case I need to handle and I wanted to use FCM but can't because it needs the internet connection.

Basically, I want to send a signal from one app to my `localserver` and then the  `localserver` sends a post to another app via LAN, so I can't have an internet connection.

How can I achieve this?
Do I really need to use an external service to manage the connections to my devices?

Comment: what data are you planning to pass?

Comment: I wanted to pass a json string.

Edit: But not a too complicated object something small

Answer (score 0):

this is what i did in receiving and reading the json from my own wcf.

import http:
`import { Http } from '@angular/http';`

add this to your constructor: 
`public http: Http`

getting the data from uri:

```
this.http.get('http://your_url').map(res => res.text()).subscribe(data => {
        console.log("XML MO: "+data.toString());  

        this.DataBind(data);
```

reading the response:

DataBind(data: any) {

```
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data.toString(),"text/xml");

    this.customerTitle = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("myData")     
  }
```

and in your html file:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>My Data</ion-label>
  <ion-input enabled="false" type="text" [(ngModel)]="myData"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

you should also know that ion-input is a textfield. And it should work already

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not what im looking for. What you are doing is an http get to an webservice and then handle the response from the server.  What i want to do is: 

- My app to have some kind of listener that receives post data from my webservice.
- Do something depending on the data received.

Comment: you mean your app will be the one sending data? and what do you mean by listener that receives post data from my webservice. why post when you want to receive something?

Comment: No what i meant is that my app will receive data from my webservice. Webservice(POST) -> App(Response). The one who will send the data will be the webservice.

Comment: and you want to trigger it manually or the app will trigger it?

Comment: The data sent by the webservice will be triggered by an user action.

Comment: I think "ethically" speaking getting a data from a webservice shouldn't be used via post because you are "getting" a data. But if that's what you want, it's possible.

Comment: Someone asked the same question as i did on this topic: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22302203/cordova-plugin-for-push-notification-that-listen-to-my-own-webservice). So yeah I can't do it without the FCM